# Is there possibility to call real method on spring ConversionService mock?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

Like in title, is it possible to call real method on ConversionSevice mock?

Exapmple, when I do something like this:

```
private static final Date REQUEST_DATE = new Date();

@Mock
ConversionService conversionService;

@InjectMocks
ClaimRequestToClaimRequestTypeConverter converter = new ClaimRequestToClaimRequestTypeConverter();

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void convertTest() throws Exception {
    when(conversionService.convert(eq(REQUEST_DATE), eq(XMLGregorianCalendar.class))).thenCallRealMethod();

    ClaimRequest claim = new ClaimRequest();
    ClaimRequestType claimType = converter.convert(claim);

    verify(conversionService, times(3)).convert(eq(REQUEST_DATE), eq(XMLGregorianCalendar.class));
    verify(conversionService, times(2)).convert(isA(ClaimRequestAction.class), eq(ClaimRequestActionType.class));
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(conversionService);
}
```

I'm getting:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot call real method on java interface. Interface does not have any implementation!
Calling real methods is only possible when mocking concrete classes.
//correct example:
when(mockOfConcreteClass.doStuff()).thenCallRealMethod();
```

Mockito version: 1.8.5

Spring version: 3.2.8

Comment: Well obviously no you are mocking an interface so there is nothing to call for real.

Comment: is there a reason you can't mock the implementation instead of the interface?

Comment: You could use an `Answer` to call any method you need... But of course, that only works if the method in question does not need any other parts of the (theoretical) object state.